# grabbing from data set with mulitple json roots

Tags: python, json

I have a data set with multiple JSON roots, and trying to access values for each category per json object.

So the data set i have is from this:

```
data = {
   "Engine":{
      "passed_count":1,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":4088,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[

      ]
   },
   "Management Web Console":{
      "passed_count":0,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":12067,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[

      ]
   }
}
{
   "Engine":{
      "passed_count":3,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":4088,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[

      ]
   },
   "Management Web Console":{
      "passed_count":0,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":12067,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[

      ]
   }
}
```

In this example i just used 2 of the same data sets, even though in reality its 3 of them with the same keys and categories, just different values

What i'm trying to accomplish is to grab the value of 'passed_count' for each category for each data set.

Is there anyway in python to split up the 2 data sets above (in `data`) so i can access the values by doing something like this

```
 for value in data1:
        print(value['passed_count'])
        ## 1
        ## 0
 for value in data2:
        print(value['passed_count']
        ## 3
        ## 0
```

**EDIT:**

For clarification the `data` variable is created inside a for loop.  So when i `print(data)` it returns with 3 dictionaries(hence the multiple roots).  I am trying to extract data from this variable when i should be splitting up this variable into 3 separate dictionaries or format them so i able to grab values from them.

Comment: your `data` as shown above isn't a valid json format. Can you fix that?

Comment: Thats the problem, it's not valid json because it has multiple JSON root elements... I'm trying to figure out how to clean it up so each "root element" is its own `data` variable

Comment: ahhhhh. ok. I see. Is it always in the same "form" though? If it is, you can simply read it in as a string, do a small little bit of string manipulation, then work with it then

Comment: is the json file have each root on separate lines?

Comment: and I'm also assuming you are reading this in from a text or json file? I guess I'd need to see the source of the data that youre getting in order to figure out how to stroe that into python, to then parse it

Comment: I should have said this, but the data variable above is created through a `for loop` so if i were to print `data` it would give me 3 data sets.  I am able to access the "Categories" (ie. Engine) from this variable but not able to access `passed_count` seeing as though it would return multiple values

Comment: ok. how about in your `for loop`, append each of the `data` into a list, so then you'd have a list of those elements?

Comment: What is exactly your problem? An input file containing multiple json strings or how to process a loop where each iteration returns a Python dictionnary? I am sorry but I cannot understand what is *a data set with multiple json roots*...

Answer (score 1):

You could grab those `keys`, then just use the index positions as your "data1", "data2", etc, to iterate through those:

**Note:**

I had to slightly alter the `data` to fit json format

```
data = [
        {"Engine":{
      "passed_count":1,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":4088,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[]
   },
   "Management Web Console":{
      "passed_count":0,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":12067,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[]
   }
},
{"Engine":{
      "passed_count":3,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":4088,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[]
   },
   "Management Web Console":{
      "passed_count":0,
      "blocked_count":0,
      "untested_count":12067,
      "failed_count":0,
      "reviewed_count":0,
      "test_harness_issue_count":0,
      "bug_failure_count":0,
      "defect_list":[]
   }
}
   ]



data_keys = list(data[0].keys())

# data1, which is represented as key from index 0
for value in data:
    print (value[data_keys[0]]['passed_count'])


# data2, which is represented as key from index 1
for value in data:
    print (value[data_keys[1]]['passed_count'])
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but don't know how to take my `data` variable, and make it in the format you have to be able to grab those values

Comment: I'm thinking you'll have to "construct" it as you're looping through to make that set.